# Saving web-pages using batch file

Tags: html, batch-file, windows-7, cmd

> it any way to let me save or snap a file to my computer in every 1 hour

http://aqicn.org/city/beijing/

> this is the webpage I want to save or snap.
>   i have tried before *WGET*, but since it is third party software, which lecture dun want.
>   so is there got any solution? 
>   my pc is window 7 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Telnet** should help.

telnet http://aqicn.org/ to `port 80 (HTTP)` or `443 (HTTPS)` in cmd and do an `HTTP GET` request. I don't really know how to automate the process though.

Comment: Can u provide me the cmd or batch file full command? as i beginner for programming so i cant really know the programming code. thank you

Comment: @NewBie_PleaseHelp I cannot create a code for you. You must create a code for yourself, and if it fails, we can debug it for you.

This website is not for people making codes for you, It's about people helping you make your code.